# querying a db table once when application starts in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have language table:

```
  language_code
  country
```

I wanna query language table once when application starts and hold it somewhere  and use this data everywhere.

and important thing not query every time this table if results exists in somewhere.

is there a way to do it in laravel?

Comment: Perhaps show us the structure of your application?

Comment: Add some code somewhere that somehow solves this problem somewhat. Can you be more specific?